# Existe ganho de performance ao utilizar View's no SQL?

Tags: sql, desempenho, sql-view

As `View`'s são tabelas virtuais, resultantes de consultas `SQL`, como no exemplo:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

A partir disto, podemos atualizar ou excluir uma `View`, mas não podemos editar os dados diretamente nelas.

Há algum ganho de performance ao utilizar elas, ou a utilização está relacionada apenas com redução de código nas consultas da aplicação?

Comment: Epa! Sim você pode alterar dados através de uma view no MS SQL referência: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx

Comment: Realmente, no MS SQL as Views permitem gravação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Criar uma View em si, não produz ganho em performance. Porém, há algumas coisas que podem ser feitas para melhorar sua performance:

1. No SQL Server você pode criar índices para a View, melhorando sua performance.
2. No Oracle, você pode criar Materialized Views, que também provê ganhos em performance.

Comment: Como tudo em SQL sim você pode ter ganho ou perda de performance dependendo da situação e da implementação. No caso para criar índices a view precisa ser "schema bounded" (equivalente ao materialized)

Answer (score 2):

Ganha-se na reutilização do código e em alguns casos na performance pois a SQL encapsulada da view já está compilada.